# Coversion from datetime of format "01 Oct 2012 23:59:59:000" to "01-10-2012 23:59:59" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My database contains the "From Date" in the form **"2012-10-01 23:59:59.000"** while taking the value to front end its comming as **"01 Oct 2012 23:59:59:000"**. So how can i get the date without "Oct" format.

I tried this also

```
     foreach (DataRow dr in _dt.Rows)
    {
        dr["FromDt"] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt zzz}", dr["FromDt"]);
        dr["ToDt"] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dr["ToDt"]);  
    }
```

But Couldn't..

I refered all those quires iin stackoverflow to my best knowledge. Please sugest some ways.
Thanks in advance

I Used these following trils also-

```
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dr["FromDt"].ToString());
        dr["FromDt"] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt zzz}", dr["FromDt"]);
```

Comment: have you used datetimepicker ?

Comment: @knowledge Seeker- I checked out ur answer , it cause error as-

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
Any other suggestions?

Comment: You are not performing any date checks to see if date is null or in wrong format....

Answer (score 2):

Try out this

Convert the field to DateTime dt & then apply formatting this should work

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dr["FromDt"];
String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz}", dt)
```

if you don't want time zone then you should use it as

```
String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dt)
```

You can use any of the formats if you want to  from examples below

```
 // create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

    String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
    String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
    String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
    String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
    String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
    String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
    String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
    String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
    String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
    String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone

// date separator in german culture is "." (so "/" changes to ".")
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)


// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate
String.Format("{0:T}", dt);  // "4:05:07 PM"                      LongTime
String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"          LongDate
String.Format("{0:f}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05 PM"  LongDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:F}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05:07 PM" FullDateTime
String.Format("{0:g}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"                ShortDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"             ShortDate+LongTime
String.Format("{0:m}", dt);  // "March 09"                        MonthDay
String.Format("{0:y}", dt);  // "March, 2008"                     YearMonth
String.Format("{0:r}", dt);  // "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT"   RFC1123
String.Format("{0:s}", dt);  // "2008-03-09T16:05:07"             SortableDateTime
String.Format("{0:u}", dt);  // "2008-03-09 16:05:07Z"            UniversalSortabl
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,As you told to use

 DateTime.Parse DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dr["FromDt"].ToString()); 

It Cause error as-
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @ Teju,  use `String strDate = dr["FromDT"].ToString();`  to see if it works and use `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);` This should work otherwise you have to check on data first to see if it is in correct format or null, It works fine for me when i use it as `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-01 23:59:56.000");
    //01 Oct 2012 23:59:59:000
   Reponse.write( String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:sss }", dt));
`

Comment: Thanks again for reply.


        foreach (DataRow dr in _dt.Rows)
        {
            String strDate = dr["FromDt"].ToString();
            **DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);**
            dr["FromDt"] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt zzz}", dr["FromDt"]);
           
It cause again error on bolded line as
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
            dr["ToDt"] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dr["ToDt"]);  
        }

Comment: Hey ,
strDate="01 Oct 2012 13:30:00:000" on breakpoint 
So when i parse it to next line as

**DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate); **

Cause error as above..

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-01 23:59:56.000");    
This will work fine, but in my string month is in "Oct" format.That is causing error.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** That code *would* work for a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` value. However, in this case the *type* of object in `dr["FromDt"]` is *not* a DateTime or DateTimeOffset value.

"Works as expected":

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",DateTime.Now) // -> 2012-10-09
```

Observed behavior; "foo" is a string and the format modifier ignored:

```
string.Format("{0:junk}","foo") // -> foo
```

If the value happens to be a String (hopefully it was *accidentally* converted while reading from the database - the value shown looks suspiciously like `someDateTime.ToString()` - and is not as such in the database) then:

1. Fix/remove the conversion (correct) or,
2. Convert it back into a DateTime first (hack) :)

Comment: @TejuMB "That code would work for a DateTime or DateTimeOffset value." - so find out what makes it *not* a DateTime value. What *is* the value really? Why?

Comment: thanks for your time pst,

In my database the value of FromDt(datetime) is "2012-10-01 23:59:59.000"
But when i take this value to front end via datatable its comming as "01 Oct 2012 23:59:59:000".Check my edited question again please.

Comment: @TejuMB Something is likely converting it to a String then - find out what it is. I believe my conclusion is correct and I have provided examples of justification. (That is, **verify it *is* a DateTime in the DataTable and also verify the column *is* of a suitable type**. I doubt that it is, because your code is trying to shove junk values back in.)

Comment: Hey,Thanks again to reply.. yes i got the difference 
in my database the value is  **01 Oct 2012 13:30:00.000**
  But when passing the same to front end its showing as **01 Oct 2012 13:30:00:000**   U can see the "." has changed to ":" when i send the data from SQL to my front end. Why is it so?

Comment: Yes i got finally, while sending data from SQL to front end i have converted its type to string in SQL so "." has converrted to ":".

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["FromDt"].ToString(), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None);
var output = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Edit: changed to use ParseExact, to accommodate the slightly odd format of the input string.

Comment: Thanks for reply the above code results in

Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Complaint\Entry\SDF\sdfLeaveUpdate.aspx.cs 70 28 http://localhost/Complaint/

Comment: Sorry about that - I have added a .ToString() to the object to make it parsable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using datetimepicker then simply go into properties of it and then set format property as short. Then whie showing date you should show it as>>

```
dtpFrmDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

I thin it will give you desired result.